# ZingChart line update scale x in Angular2

Tags: angular, charts, zingchart

I am using ZingChart in my angular2 app. 
I am trying to update also the scale-x of a line graph.
but couldn't find the api for that:

```
export class App {
  charts : Chart[];

  @ViewChild(ZingChart)
  chart: ZingChart;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.charts = [{
      id : 'chart-1',
      data : {
        type : 'line',
        series : [{
          values :[2,3,4,5,3,3,2]
        }],
      },
      height : 400,
      width : 600
    }]
  }


  update(){
    this.charts[0].data.series[0].values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    //this.charts[0].data.x.value=[1,2,3,4,5,6]; ??? 
    this.chart.update();
  }
}
```

here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/71pD7eQdYnnEUxVdgxVi)

Comment: What are you trying to update on scale-x? Do you want to display text instead of numbers? Do you want to change the label on the axis?

Comment: @nardecky  I want to have the last 12 hours. so now it is 3 scale x should be [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] and when it will be 4 it should start from 4 i.e [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

Answer (score 2):

So what you are looking for is scale-x `values` or `labels`. This will determine what is displayed on your x-axis. Since you want to display these labels as a linear measure of time you do not need to set the scale with `minValue`, `maxValue` and `step`. But you should be aware that's an option [here.](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-types-linear-scale)

The documentation you need for your demo using `labels` is [here](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-types-category-scale)

[Updated Your Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/VuROB10NMvDkxaAXlOsC?p=preview)